# How can I change the module context of an RSpec describe block?

Tags: ruby, rspec, activesupport

I've got a spec for an object that's in a number of levels of modules.  Something like this:

```
describe Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget do
  it "should == another Widget for the same Doohickey" do
    doohickey = stub
    Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget.new(doohickey).should == Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget.new(doohickey)
  end

  it "should != another Widget for a different Doohickey" do
    one_doohickey = stub
    another_doohickey = stub
    Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget.new(one_doohickey).should == Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget.new(another_doohickey)
  end
end
```

That's a lot of repetition, and it makes it look like I'm using an object
from some other namespace.  I'd like to set the context of the spec to
`Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux`.  The following works surprisingly well:

```
module Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux
  describe Widget do
    it "should == another Widget for the same Doohickey" do
      doohickey = stub
      Widget.new(doohickey).should == Widget.new(doohickey)
    end

    it "should != another Widget for a different Doohickey" do
      one_doohickey = stub
      another_doohickey = stub
      Widget.new(one_doohickey).should == Widget.new(another_doohickey)
    end
  end
end
```

There's only one problem.  Since I'm in Rails, I'm depending on
ActiveSupport's dependency management to autoload the `Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux`
module.  Before, that happened when I mentioned `Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget`.
Now, I'm defining the module myself, so the real definition of the module in
`foo/bar/baz/quux.rb` is never loaded.

How can I change the constant-lookup context for my spec *without* defining
the module myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `described_class` helper...

```
describe Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget do
  it "has described_class helper" do
    described_class.should == Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget
  end
end
```

Or, for the lol:

```
describe Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget do
  def Widget
    described_class
  end

  it "has described_class helper" do
    Widget.should == Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, `described_class` is what we've been using, but I find it harder to read.  I'd like the call into the object to look the way any other object in the same namespace would call it.  Oh, well.  I'm going to see if anyone can beat this answer before I accept it.

Comment: And another thing, if you want to refer to other classes in the same namespace described_class is no good either. Also looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you assign that to a variable ?

```
widget_class = Foo::Bar::Baz::Quux::Widget
```

this should DRY out the code a little bit. Just a thought.